# mongoDB: get field value of an array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb

I want to get the value of the field `30` in the object (in the array `test`) with the id `ePce6fBAHx9KeKjuM`.

```
{
    "_id" : "nAwt3b76c24mZfqxz",
    "title" : "test",
    "test" : [
        {
            "4" : false,
            "15" : false,
            "30" : false,
            "75" : true,
            "id" : "ePce6fBAHx9KeKjuM"
        }
    ]
}
```

So this result would be `false`

I tried something like

```
var result = Collection.findOne({_id: 'nAwt3b76c24mZfqxz'}).test;
```

But this would give me the complete array. But I need the selected object and only a selected field of this object (ie. `30`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`test` is just a JS array. Use normal array syntax to access its elements:

```
var result = Collection.findOne({_id: 'nAwt3b76c24mZfqxz'}).test["30"];
```

**EDIT:**

To retrieve the whole object with only 1 element of the array use projection, as of zangw's answer. Following your comment to test element itself:

```
db.getCollection('a').find(
    // put your nested document's condition instead of `$exists`
    {_id: 'nAwt3b76c24mZfqxz', test:{ $elemMatch: { "30": {$exists: true}}}},
    // add other fields you like to retrieve, e.g. "title":1
    {"test.30":1}
)
```

Comment: But this doesn't consider, that test is an array, and I need the result of the object with the given id.

Comment: It would be nice to have an example of expected result, as it is not quite clear what you are trying to retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
Collection.find({{_id: 'nAwt3b76c24mZfqxz'}}, {'test.30': 1, 'test.id': 1});
```

To select the whole `test` array as following without `_id`

```
Collection.find({{_id: 'nAwt3b76c24mZfqxz'}}, {'test': 1, '_id': 0});
```

Comment: But I need the exact object of the array `test` (id = ePce6fBAHx9KeKjuM).

Comment: @user3142695, add {`test` : 1} to select this field out.. Is it meet your requirement? or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but this just selects the field generally. I have to check the defined object in this array. So if there isn't an object with the given id, the result should be empty/false.